# embed an html file with styles, javascript using ShadowDOM webcomponents

Tags: javascript, web-component, native-web-component

I have a html file with css, html, javascript.

Usecase: Do not use iframes but needed to import above html file along with

> css, js

completely onto another application.

I am looking at alternatives without using iframes and came across webcomponents, shadow dom.
Does anyone has done anything like this using webcomponents/shadow dom or any ideas on how to achieve this.

Thanks,
Sri

Comment: Can you be a _lotttt_ more specific and include several code samples of what you want?

Comment: Take inspiration from the Native JavaScript [``<load-file>`` Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd) I blogged about.